# Loading a jbitmap with data

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am developing an Android app with Delphi 10.2 Tokyo as a developer tool. In an effort to print to a Zebra printer, I need to send an image as a `JBitmap`. I can not find any light on the subject how to load that `JBitmap`. I have a `TBitmap` containing the picture. I just need to juggle it over to that `JBitmap`.

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  FMX.Graphics, FMX.Surfaces, FMX.Helpers.Android;

function BitmapToJBitmap(const ABitmap: TBitmap): JBitmap;
var
  LSurface: TBitmapSurface;
begin
  Result := TJBitmap.JavaClass.createBitmap(ABitmap.Width, ABitmap.Height, TJBitmap_Config.JavaClass.ARGB_8888);
  LSurface := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  try
    LSurface.Assign(ABitmap);
    SurfaceToJBitmap(LSurface, Result);
  finally
    LSurface.Free;
  end;
end;
```